# Share pdf file via whatsapp from my app on Android

Tags: android, pdf, whatsapp

I am try to send pdf file from my app to whatsapp, and here is the code, 
but something missing!!

it opens whatsapp and i can choose a contact but it says "sharing failed"!

the code

```
String PLACEHOLDER = "file:///android_asset/QUOT_2016_10(test).pdf";
File f = new File(PLACEHOLDER);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);

Intent share = new Intent();
share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hi");
share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.setType("application/pdf");

activity.startActivity(share);
```

Comment: I firgured out the problem, and here is the answer if somebody had the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem, and here is the answer if somebody had the same issue. The problem was that I am trying to open the pdf from the asset folder which did n't work, and if would try to open the pdf from the download folder for example, it would work. Please refer to the the code below for the final correct way:

```
File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
        (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "ref Number from Quotation.pdf");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);

Intent share = new Intent();
share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("application/pdf");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

activity.startActivity(share);
```

Comment: getting the error `The file format is not supported` for the PDF file stored in the downloads folder of the internal storage of my device..

Comment: how to send to specific mobile no?

Comment: @PrajwalWaingankar did you know how to send a specific mobile number?

Comment: @amit did you find any solution ???

Comment: @daksh i uploaded the file to Google drive, changed its link to public, and then opened it by the following code ```startActivity (new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.parse (pdfURL), "application/pdf"));``` pdfURL is your Google drive link..

Answer (score 1):

```
 File outputPath= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyPdf/example.pdf");//change with your path

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
            getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", outputPath);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share it"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's technically wrong, what if someone has WhatsApp business or want to share file on gmail then use this...

```java
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, _text);
shareIntent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(_file));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser( shareIntent, "Share"));
```

In this u just have to add text and file
Text u attach will become subject in gmail and if you are sharing image on WhatsApp then text will become as image caption